# Why do they censor brand names out of movies?

Tags: censorship

In a lot of movies there are recognizable stores and places that seem to get censored out of the film. So, for example, in The Equalizer (2014), the main character works at a big box hardware store that is obviously Home Depot or Lowes, but has been anonymized as "Home Mart":

[image: Equalizer workplace]

Comment: Not sure 'censorship' is the right tag here.  Censorship is externally imposed cuts or changes to a movie - usually by a government agency. There is nothing stopping movies using brand names other than (a) a desire to only do it if they are being paid to do so and/or (b) to avoid legal disputes over how the brand is depicted or the association of the brand with negative characters or imagery.

Comment: The duplicate question talks about branded products rather than stores - but I believe this is completely the same question.